# What is a First Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **First Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

$$
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ First }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[lightblue]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{   first}&\text{  third}\\ \hline
\text{    saturn}&\text{jupiter}\\ \hline
\text{    dog}&\text{turtle}\\ \hline
\text{    put}&\text{out}\\ \hline
\text{    washington}&\text{paris}\\ \hline
\text{    red}&\text{black}\\ \hline
\text{  thought}&\text{ though}\\ \hline
\text{    cork}&\text{  cook}\\ \hline
\text{    conundrum}&\text{ puzzle}\\ \hline
\text{    astonishment}&\text{  surprise}\\ \hline
\text{    bar}&\text{foo}\\ \hline
\text{    invalid}&\text{valid}\\ \hline
\text{    auto}&\text{mobile}\\ \hline
\text{    plot}&\text{agitates}\\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}$$

CSV version:

```
First Words™,   Not First Words™

first,          third
saturn,         jupiter
dog,            turtle
put,            out
washington,     paris
red,            black
thought,        though
cork,           cook
conundrum,      puzzle
astonishment,   surprise
bar,            foo
invalid,        valid
auto,           mobile
plot,           agitates
```

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

---

**Hint:**

> Trivially, *pizza*, *apple*, *macaroni*, *burrito*, *tofu* are not First Words. However, *ale* is one. Why is that?

Comment: of course "first" is a First Word :P

Comment: Is it that they all end with a comma?

Comment: I added an interesting case of a First Word

Comment: @Keelhaul I think you should add at least one pair that invalidates my solution. As it stands it still works.

Comment: @Paul Panzer You're right, I added the examples I gave you in the comments

Comment: A hint has been added

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: Got it at last:

> first = prime

> Write 1 for consonants and 0 for vowels, read as binary number and check whether the result is prime.

Comment: You got it, well done ;)